# How to input char array in c++ in a single line?

Tags: c++, input, c++14

I just encountered an input statement for char array in c++ and I didn't understand how it works.

```
char s[100];
cin >> s + 1;
cout << s + 1;
```

Input : Harold

Output: Harold

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: It works exactly like any other `char` array. Sorry we don't know how much of C++ you know, so it's a bit difficult to pick a starting point for an explanation. Why exactly are you confused about these lines?

Comment: If it said `((&s[0]) + 1)` would you understand it?

Comment: Make these changes `char s[100] = "a";` Now at the end add `cout <<  '\n' << s << '\n';` With that, can you tell what is going on?

Comment: @n.m. I was wondering how it works. We used to use loops to input an array but didn't know about this. Now I get this. Thanks a lot

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah i got this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks a lot. I tried it and it helped me understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When you give the input 'Harold', the indices from 1 to 6 (As you do with `s+1`) will be assigned with the given characters. Other indices still contain garbages.
This array looks like this: `{'X','H','a','r','o','l','d','X','X',........}` (Here 'X' means garbage)

But the thing is that when you want to get this array as output from `s+1` (literally `s[1]`), It shows only the value you have assigned. Hence the output `'Harold'`.